# Find algorithm for equation

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

I need algorithm for this problem: Find $x,y$ from the equation: $c=ax+by$, where a,b,c are given natural numbers and $(a,b)=1$  (the greatest common factor of $a$ and $b$ is $1$).

Comment: There is no $x$ in this equation.

Comment: Look again more carefully.

Comment: @barakmanos There was no $x$ but I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first solve $ax+by=1$ since $a$ and $b$  are coprime. This is done using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

You will get a solution $(x_0,y_0)$.All other solutions are $(x_0+kb,y_0-ka),\  k\in\mathbf Z $. Now the solutions for the original equation is obtained multiplying the former results by $c$.

As an example, the equation $5x+2y=1$ has a trivial solution (needless to deploy the E.E.A. here): $(x_0,y_0)=(1,-2)$ and the general solution has the form: $$(x,y)=(1+2k,-2-5k),\ k\in\mathbf. Z$$

Then the equation  $5x+2y=13$ has the solution $(x_0,y_0)=(13,-26)$ and the general solution has the form: $$(x,y)=(13+2k,-26-5k),\ k\in\mathbf. Z$$

Comment: Can you please make an example for 13=5x+2y ?

Comment: @Abbey: I added the example.

Comment: And that (13,-26) is obtained from the previous result (1,-2) this way (1*13,-2*13) ?

Comment: Exactly: since 1×5 –2×2=1, it suffices to multiply both sides of this equality by 13 to get 13×5 –26×2 = 13.

Answer (score 4):

Have you heard of Euclid's algorithm?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: No. I have not. I do not think it solves my problem.

Comment: @Abbey Then I suggest you read about it, starting from the link I provided. Read the part on Bézout's identity in detail. It solves your problem.

Comment: I've read Berzout's identity. But there we have g = sa + tb where (a,b)=g. Here we have (a,b)=1.

Comment: @Abbey Meaning you are able to find such $x,y$ that $ax+by = 1$. Can you modify this equation so the right side will be equal to $c$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this elementary transform of the equation:

$$c=ax+by=ax-bx+bx+by=(a-b)x+b(x+y)=a'x'+b'y',$$ where $a'::=a-b,b'::=b,x'::=x,y'::=x+y$.

The equation keeps the same form, but the coefficients have changed.

Now do this repatedly in such a way that you always subtract the small coefficient from the large one.

In the end the small coefficient will be $0$ and the equation will reduce to
$$c=a^{(i)}x^{(i)},$$which is immediately solved. Then you backtrack to obtain $x,y$ (using $x=x',y=y'-x'$).

Example:
$$7x+3y=15 $$
$$4x'+3y'=15$$
$$x''+3y''=15$$
$$x'''+2y'''=15$$
$$x''''+y''''=15$$
$$x'''''+0y'''''=15$$
Backtracing, the solution is (with $y'''''$ being indeterminate, let $k$):
$$x'''''=15,y'''''=k$$
$$x''''=15-k,y''''=k$$
$$x'''=15-2k,y'''=k$$
$$x''=15-3k,y''=k$$
$$x'=15-3k,y'=4k-15$$
$$x=15-3k,y=7k-30$$

This is indeed an algorithm as every step is clearly defined and uses elementary operations. It is also guaranteed to terminate in a finite number of steps because the coefficients decrease on every step.

This forms the basis of the well-known **extended Euclidean algorithm**, which adds two improvements:

- the backtracking can be done at the same time as the forward steps by clever bookkeeping,
- the subtraction $a=a-b$ can be replaced by a division remainder $a=a\bmod b$ to accelerate the decay.

---

UPDATE: case $5x+2y=13$
$$5x+2y=13$$
$$3x'+2y'=13$$
$$x''+2y''=13$$
$$x'''+y'''=13$$
$$x''''+0y''''=13$$
$$x''''=13,y''''=k$$
$$x'''=13-k,y'''=k$$
$$x''=13-2k,y''=k$$
$$x'=13-2k,y'=3k-13$$
$$x=13-2k,y=5k-26$$

Comment: The condition $gcd(a,b)=1$ is not required by the algorithm. If $a^{(i)}$ [which can be shown to be $gcd(a,b)$] does not divide $c$, the equation is just diagnosed as impossible.